# JSON Validation error when adding more than one line to json

Tags: json

I tried to check my json but i got "Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'"

i'm unsure as to why, i have also tried adding a comma at the end of }, but ot no avail.
any help would be much appreciated!

```
{"prompt":
                    "can i change my feeling of being worthless to everyone ? i ' m going through some things with my feelings and myself . i barely sleep and i do nothing but think about how i ' m worthless and how i shouldn ' t be here . i ' ve never tried or contemplated suicide . i ' ve always wanted to fix my issues , but i never get around to it . how can i change my feeling of being worthless to everyone ?"
                ,
                "completion": [
                    "maybe lower your expectations for a bit",
                    "if you are whole - heartedly committed to moving past the sexual and romantic parts of your relationship and just having a friendship than refraining from all the touching would be a good place to start",
                    "very often , one person wants to deal with the conflict right away or shortly thereafter and the other person wants to wait",
                    "\" my best guess is that your boyfriend is triggered by some previous relationship , either romantic or in childhood",
                    "can he do that for you",
                    "\" friend \" is a broad category",
                    "in general , i usually let the client decide when this should occur , sometimes with some clients it will be a joint agreement , but even in that case it should weigh mostly on what the client feels",
                    "who takes care of your son , is a significant part of getting over your heartbreak",
                    "if everyone thinks you ' re worthless , then maybe you need to find new people to hang out with . seriously , the social context in which a person lives is a big influence in self - esteem . otherwise , you can go round and round trying to understand why you ' re not worthless , then go back to the same crowd and be knocked down again . there are many inspirational messages you can find in social media . maybe read some of the ones which state that no person is worthless , and that everyone has a good purpose to their life . also , since our culture is so saturated with the belief that if someone doesn ' t feel good about themselves that this is somehow terrible . bad feelings are part of living . they are the motivation to remove ourselves from situations and relationships which do us more harm than good . bad feelings do feel terrible . your feeling of worthlessness may be good in the sense of motivating you to find out that you are much better than your feelings today ."
                
            ]}
        
    
    
        
        
            
                {"prompt":
                    "can i change my feeling of being worthless to everyone ? i ' m going through some things with my feelings and myself . i barely sleep and i do nothing but think about how i ' m worthless and how i shouldn ' t be here . i ' ve never tried or contemplated suicide . i ' ve always wanted to fix my issues , but i never get around to it . how can i change my feeling of being worthless to everyone ?"
                ,
                "completion": [
                    "suicide is a very traumatic loss and affects survivors significantly",
                    "encontrar un consejero escolar o hablar con tu pediatra puede ser el primer paso para obtener las herramientas que te ayudaran a alcanzar tus metas de salud fisica y emocional",
                    "you have some social anxiety that is a bit beyond what the average person might feel",
                    "until you attract a partner who will love and appreciate you , develop relationships with co - workers and classmates , neighbors , so that you have some quality of giving and being given by someone",
                    "through family therapy , you could address family dynamics , negotiate solutions to current family or individual challenges and identify ways to support each other",
                    "bring peace to these feelings and commit to move on to provide your mom love",
                    "then you would look for a bereavement or grief specialist",
                    "i recommend you see a therapist who does cognitive behavioural therapy , which can help you understand the roots of your fears and learn how to manage them more successfully",
                    "hello , and thank you for your question and seeking advice on this . feelings of worthlessness is unfortunately common . in fact , most people , if not all , have felt this to some degree at some point in their life . you are not alone . changing our feelings is like changing our thoughts - it ' s hard to do . our minds are so amazing that the minute you change your thought another one can be right there to take it ' s place . without your permission , another thought can just pop in there . the new thought may feel worse than the last one ! my guess is that you have tried several things to improve this on your own even before reaching out on here . people often try thinking positive thoughts , debating with their thoughts , or simply telling themselves that they need to \" snap out of it \" - which is also a thought that carries some self - criticism . some people try a different approach , and there are counselors out there that can help you with this . the idea is that instead of trying to change the thoughts , you change how you respond to them . you learn skills that allow you to manage difficult thoughts and feelings differently so they don ' t have the same impact on you that they do right now . for some people , they"
                
            ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 objects in there.

Wrap the whole thing in [], and add a comma between the two objects:

```
[ 
    { content },
    { content } 
]
```